# MVEL Expression with multiple conditions

Tags: eclipse, mvel

I am trying to get an MVEL expression to work but am having probelms.  I am tyring to determine if date defined as a property falls between two other dates.

```
props['ExistingStartDate'] >= props['current_period_start_date'] && props['ExistingStartDate'] <= props['current_period_end_date']
```

So in this case, my ExistingStartDate = 3/6/14, current_period_start_date = 3/3/14 and current_period_end_date = 3/16/14

I am expecting this to be true.  I feel like there must be something wrong with my syntax.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses for each term for multiple conditions:

```
(props['ExistingStartDate'] >= props['current_period_start_date']) && (props['ExistingStartDate'] <= props['current_period_end_date'])
```

Also, the `props` references may not have the correct syntax depending on what type of Java object it is.